# Fast Monte Carlo of Local Volatility Model

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, programming, performance, local

I want to compute option prices via a Monte Carlo simulation. The model implemented is a Markov process, following the SDE :

```
d X_t = alpha * dt + beta^(1/2) * d W_t
```

where alpha lives in R^2, beta in R^(2*2) and is Positive semi definite. (^(1/2) -> cholesky)
Therefore, X_t is in R^2.

I obtain value for beta and alpha after a resolution of an HJB equation using finite differences on a mesh grid (yielding arrays `sigmasqX`,`sigmasqY` and `sigmaXY`, which I then interpolate to obtain value of beta and alpha at `(t,X_t)`).

My problem is, I then run a Monte Carlo simulation to obtain option prices, to derive implied volatility from, but the simulation takes forever on a very limited 20 000 path simulation.

Here are the broad strokes of my strategy :

- I start with the initial `X_0`
- I generate a normal sample of size `t_size*sample`, where `tsize` is the length of my time vector, and `sample` the number of paths generated
- I interpolate using `spicy.RectBivariateSpline` over the `sigma` arrays.
  Here are the nested `for` loops :

```
for j in np.arange(sample):

        X = np.array([np.log(var.S0), var.x2_0])
        broke = False

        for i in np.arange(1,ind[0]+2) :
            sigsqX  = L0[i-1]
            sigsqY  = L1[i-1]
            sigXY   = L2[i-1]
            
            beta[0,0] = sigsqX(X[0],X[1])
            beta[1,1] = sigsqY(X[0],X[1])
            beta[0,1] = sigXY(X[0],X[1])
            beta[1,0] = beta[0,1]
            
            if not isPD(beta) :
                beta = nearestPD(beta)
                
            alpha = r_rate-q_rate-0.5*beta[0,0]*np.ones(2)

            bet_sq = np.linalg.cholesky(beta)
            X[0] =  X[0] + alpha[0]*dt + np.dot(bet_sq, W[j,i-1])[0]*np.sqrt(dt)
            X[1] =  X[1] + alpha[1]*dt + np.dot(bet_sq, W[j,i-1])[1]*np.sqrt(dt)
            
            if X[0] > x1vec[-1] or X[0] < x1vec[0]:
                broke = True
                break
                
            if X[1] > x2vec[-1] or X[1] < x2vec[0]:
                broke = True
                break

        if broke == False :
            vix_v_t1.append(X[1])
            
            for i in np.arange(ind[0]+2,ind[1]+2) :

                sigsqX  = L0[i-1]
                sigsqY  = L1[i-1]
                sigXY   = L2[i-1]
                
                beta[0,0] = sigsqX(X[0],X[1])
                beta[1,1] = sigsqY(X[0],X[1])
                beta[0,1] = sigXY(X[0],X[1])
                beta[1,0] = beta[0,1]
                
                if not isPD(beta) :
                    beta = nearestPD(beta)
                    
                alpha = r_rate-q_rate-0.5*beta[0,0]*np.ones(2)
                bet_sq = np.linalg.cholesky(beta)
                X[0] =  X[0] + alpha[0]*dt + np.dot(bet_sq, W[j,i-1])[0]*np.sqrt(dt)
                X[1] =  X[1] + alpha[1]*dt + np.dot(bet_sq, W[j,i-1])[1]*np.sqrt(dt)

                if X[0] > x1vec[-1] or X[0] < x1vec[0]:
                    broke = True
                    break
                if X[1] > x2vec[-1] or X[1] < x2vec[0]:
                    broke = True
                    break

            if broke == False :
                spx_t1.append(X[0])
                for i in np.arange(ind[1]+2,ind[2]+2) :

                    sigsqX  = L0[i-1]
                    sigsqY  = L1[i-1]
                    sigXY   = L2[i-1]
                    
                    beta[0,0] = sigsqX(X[0],X[1])
                    beta[1,1] = sigsqY(X[0],X[1])
                    beta[0,1] = sigXY(X[0],X[1])
                    beta[1,0] = beta[0,1]
                    
                    if not isPD(beta) :
                        beta = nearestPD(beta)
                        
                    alpha = r_rate-q_rate-0.5*beta[0,0]*np.ones(2)
                    bet_sq = np.linalg.cholesky(beta)
                    X[0] =  X[0] + alpha[0]*dt + np.dot(bet_sq, W[j,i-1])[0]*np.sqrt(dt)
                    X[1] = X[1] + alpha[1]*dt + np.dot(bet_sq, W[j,i-1])[1]*np.sqrt(dt)
                    if X[0] > x1vec[-1] or X[0]<x1vec[0]:
                        broke = True
                        break
                    if X[1] > x2vec[-1] or X[1]<x2vec[0]:
                        broke = True
                        break

                if broke == False :
                    spx_t2.append(X[0])

    spot = [spx_t1, spx_t2, vix_v_t1]
    return spot
```

A few things to note :

- I check whether `beta`, and adjust it if need be, because of numerical approximation it sometimes has a tiny negative eigenvalue and corrupts the cholesky decomposition
- There are 3 linear `for` loops to walk through the entire time set because there a three maturities for options, it is easier to manage that way (not impactful here)
- Sometimes the value for `X_t` wanders outside of the grid, and breaks the simulation (because of extrapolation errors), so I implemented all these verifications (`if broke : break`)
- The `L0`, `L1` and `L2` variables are python `list` type, that hold the interpolation of the grid, at each date of the time vector.

I know *why* this code is **slow** :

- many `if` statements slow it down a lot
- finding nearest PD for beta can be costly
- using local volatility means, I can't parallelize according to NumPy's rules, the Monte Carlo process

I checked, and the interpolation is negligible (0.5 sec on average). But this path simulation takes 75 sec for 20 000 paths...

My question : **is there a way to speed up the whole process ?** I can't imagine that I am stuck with such poor execution times... (comparable to solving backward pricing PDEs which are notorious for being expansive computation wise)

Thanks !

Comment: To model path dependent options, you will need a lot more than 20k simulations. Industry standard is at least 100k, with many practitioners doing 200k to 500k.  200k simulations should not take more than half a second even on older hardware

Comment: To aid tieing out alternative code suggestions to your implementation, could you provide initial values and a result associated with those inputs.

Comment: Well yes I would love to be able to perform 500k simulations in 0.5 sec, but this code takes 75 secs to run.

Comment: @wgajate I just did thanks :)

Comment: I don't see any changes to the example you provided. The goal would be to provide an executable/runnable example that ensures the correctness of code improvements offered by the community.